Proof of Strong Convexity and Smoothness
Lemma:
Let $f$ be $\beta$-smooth and $\alpha$-strongly convex on $\mathbf{R}^n$. Then for all $x$, $y \in \mathbf{R}^n$, one has
$$(\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y))^\top(x-y)\ge \frac{\alpha \beta}{\beta + \alpha}\|x-y\|^2+\frac{1}{\beta + \alpha}\|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|^2$$
Proof attempt:
Let $\phi(x)=f(x)-\frac{\alpha}{2}\|x\|^2$. By definition of $\alpha$-strong convexity one has that $\phi$ is convex. Furthermore one can show that $\phi$ is $\beta - \alpha$ smooth. Thus one gets
$$(\nabla \phi(x)-\nabla \phi(y))^\top(x-y)\ge \frac{1}{\beta - \alpha}\|\nabla \phi(x)-\nabla \phi(y)\|^2$$
I want to know that how do I conclude this lemma?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You just have to plug in the expression for $\nabla\phi$.
